# How to delete EBS volume before or after free trail ends?

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing, amazon-ebs

I once tried to study AWS in free-trial months. After I stopped accessing this account, I noticed that I was billed for AWS. The billing management console says that I was billed for using "EBS". How can I delete these services?

[image]

I searched in a search box "EBS" but didn't find any.
I thought it might be these two and deleted all the volumes in the region, but I am not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Those are the only 2 you could be paying up for, assuming you had not performed any fast restores or used the EBS direct APIs.
https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/

Volumes and their snapshot, even if not in use, still incur storage costs.
Your free trial probably ended or you were using more than what the free tier allowed.
If you have deleted all volumes and snapshots, you will not incur any more costs.

Volumes and Snapshots are under the EBS section on the EC2 Page -

[image: EBS Section]

Comment: Thanks! I think that's the case. I know that this is so much a basic question but how I can access to that page of Elastic Block Store?

Comment: Well. There isnt any page for EBS. Its a section found on the left pane of the EC2 page.